# Excluding specific lines from being redirected

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

Suppose I am executing a script like this:

`/a/b/c/script.sh >> abc.log`

This means that all the contents/execution of script will be re-directed to `abc.log`.  If I want a particular line inside the script *not* to be re-directed to `abc.log`, then how do I do that?

Comment: How will you identify the line that you do not want?  By line number?  By regex?

Comment: Typically you would sent the output you don't want to go to stdout, to stderr.

Answer (score 3):

```
/a/b/c/script.sh >> abc.log
```

This command means that any output that `script.sh` writes to the [standard output stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) will be appended to `abc.log`

If you wish to exclude a line, or multiple lines that match a similar pattern you can use `grep -v` to accomplish this:

```
/a/b/c/script.sh | grep -v '<line-to-ignore>' >> abc.log
```

or to match a pattern (e.g. all lines that start with the word cat):

```
/a/b/c/script.sh | grep -vE '^cat' >> abc.log
```

The `-v` flag to grep means to invert the match, so any lines that match the pattern you supply will be filtered out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tool like `sed` to alter the output of `script.sh`, including "deleting" lines from the stream.  If you want to delete a line by line number you could do

```
/a/b/c/script.sh | sed -e '5d' >> abc.log
```

which in this example will remove the 5th line from the output.  Replace `5` with any line number.

```
/a/b/c/script.sh | sed -e '/<regex>/d' >> abc.log
```

will remove any line that matches the regex from the output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to select lines. Only whole streams (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` (more generally, any open file descriptors, not just these standard ones)) can be redirected.

You can simulate what you want by piping into commands that will sort out the output lines for you.

```
$ echo -e "hello\nworld"   |  #write hello and world; one per line
tee >(grep hello >1.log) |  #select line matching hello and write it to 1.log
grep -v hello > 2.log  #select lines NOT matching hello and write them to 2.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a specific line/command in the script, you can send its output to `/dev/null` inside the script.  The command inside the script will look like:

```
command > /dev/null
```

This will result in the output getting lost.  If you want it to appear on the console, you can send it to `stderr` as

```
command 2> `tty` 1>&2
```